# Slice array of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia, I have an array of arrays, say:

```
    arr = Array(Array{Float64,1},3)
    for i = 1:3
        arr[i] = [i,-i]
    end
```

Now:

```
   arr[:][1]
   2-element Array{Float64,1}:
      1.0
     -1.0
```

and

```
   arr[1][:]
    2-element Array{Float64,1}:
     1.0
    -1.0
```

It seems the only way to get the first 'column' is by comprehension

```
    pluses = [arr[i][1] for i=1:length(arr)]
    3-element Array{Any,1}:
     1.0
     2.0
     3.0
```

Is that indeed the only way? Do I lose in speed by running a for loop instead of some 'vectorized' version, or does it not matter in Julia due to different compiler?

Comment: Do you really need an Array of Arrays? Why not just use a Matrix? In general Julia does not have many facilities for working with nested Arrays; you should try to use multidimensional Arrays wherever possible. You can slice a Matrix whichever way you want :)

Comment: There is probably a way around it. The structure arises in situations as in [this tutorial](http://forio.com/products/julia-studio/tutorials/advanced/1/), where a type is defined which has one field of type `Vector`. e.g. `type Body{T}\n\tvelocity::Vector{T}\n\tend`. Then an instance of `Body` has items appended to the `velocity` field while a differential equation is being solved. I'm still digesting this, so no ideas on how to implement the same with multidimensional arrays...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done with `[]` indexing.  Each `[]` operation is an independent operation (calling getindex).  You have tried "slicing" the nested arrays by calling `arr[:][1]`. There are two independent operations here: first, `(arr[:])`, and then `(arr[:])[1]`.  But in this case `arr[:] == arr`!  Similarly for `arr[1][:]` — you're simply getting all the elements of the first vector.  That's why the two are returning the same thing.

Your comprehension is a good solution.  Unlike old* versions of MATLAB, Julia's JIT makes for loops faster than the vectorized alternatives.  It takes some getting used to if you're coming from Matlab or Python.  But it allows you to traverse these kinds of complicated structures in a very efficient manner.

With regards to your comment, the reason they used a vector of vectors in this case instead of a adding columns to a multidimensional array is that currently only vectors can grow.  You can copy your Vector of Vectors into a two dimensional array by calling `hcat(arr...)`, but if your vectors are very large (millions of elements) the copy itself will be fairly slow.

*(Recent versions of Matlab have a JIT, as well, which can make *some* for loops faster than vectorization, too, but when it kicks in is unpredictable.  For loops these days are almost always faster than arrayfun/cellfun with custom functions, in my experience).

Answer (score 12):

In Julia 0.5 or later, you can do `getindex.(arr, 1)` to extract the first element of each array in `arr`.   This is quite efficient, especially because it can [fuse with other elementwise operations using the "dot call" syntax.](http://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots)